# Angular2 How to trigger (click) event

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I have a `div` and `ion-input #fileInput type="file" accept="image/*" id="fileInput" [(ngModel)]="imageFilePath" (ionChange)="imageFilePath_change($event)" ></ion-input>`

How to simulate the click on the `ion-input` component using the `div`?

my html code is:

```
<div (click) = "fileInput.click()">
    <img src="assets/img/camera_button.png" [ngStyle]="{'position': 'fixed', 'top': '30vw', 'left': '32vw', 'height': '30px', 'color': '#0080FF'}">
    <ion-input #fileInput type="file" accept="image/*" id="fileInput" [(ngModel)]="imageFilePath" (ionChange)="imageFilePath_change($event)" ></ion-input>
    <span [ngStyle]="{'position': 'fixed', 'top': '32vw', 'left': '42vw', 'color': '#0080FF'}">{{ 'addMorePhotosBtn' | translate }}</span>
</div>
```

the error is:

```
TypeError: jit_nodeValue_20(...).click is not a function
```

Comment: `<ion-input (click) ...` ?

Comment: no i simulate the click of ion-input in a div

Comment: Your `#fileInput` so `ion-input` hasn't function named `click`

Comment: Why do you need the input to be clicked? Why not just call the component method from the original click event handler?

Comment: please you can write a simple example please?

Comment: You can accomplish this by using a label instead of a div as a click on a label is treated the same as a click on its input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an my working Example for an file while clicking div.

Html File

```
 <ion-list>
       <ion-item (click)="onImageClick()">
           <div>
              <ion-icon ios="ios-add-circle" md="md-add-circle"></ion-icon>
                  Add Files
              </div>
       </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

Typescript File

```
public onImageClick() {

    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*'); //you can change also file type as **'file/*'**
    input.setAttribute("multiple", ""); // If you dont want multiple select file pls remove this line

    input.addEventListener('change', (event: any) => {      
      let fileList: File[] = event.target.files;
      console.log("File List Object Value",fileList);
    });

    input.click();
  }
```

Worked perfect for me tested.